# Loop a linear regression over several dependant and independant variables in a data.table and store the results

Tags: r, loops, data.table, lapply, lm

I am trying to repeat a set of linear regressions on pairs of variables inside a data table.  I have three independent variables `y1`, `y2`, `y3` and 10 explanatory variables `x1` to `x10`. Some observations are missing in each series.

In the example below , I would like to repeat the second line of command for each pairs of `ys` and `xs`.

```
d <- data.table(country=rep(c('a','b','c'),c(10,10,10)),y1=rnorm(30),y2=rnorm(30),x1=runif(30),x2=runif(30))

d[(!is.na(y1) & !is.na(x1)), .(beta1=summary(lm(y1~x1))$coefficients[2,1],    p1=summary(lm(y1~x1))$coefficients[2,4])  ,by=country]
```

Comment: Could you `melt.data.table(d, id.vars = "country", measure.vars = patterns("x[0-9]", "y[0-9]"))` then run the same code but with `by = c("country", "variable")` ?

Comment: Thanks Hugh. I get this error: Error in by == c("country", "variable") : 
  comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types. i tried d$country<-as.factor(d$country) and d$variable<-as_factor(variable). i does not change anything

Comment: Only use one = like you did in your question

Comment: of course ! thanks . it works ! If I may , any quick advice to be able to retrieve which x (from 1 to 10) and which y(1to 3) has been used ? such as a column with "y1x1" , "y1x2", etc ?

Comment: Not sure -- your question suggested they were the same size so the `variable` column will specify the index.

Comment: ok thanks , they are the same size. It was more a matter of visualization/presentation of the results. I wanted to get a table whith a column explicitly mentioning which y and x were used

Comment: sorry to disturb again, i dont get why you put measure.vars = patterns("x[0-9]", "y[0-9]")) and not measure.vars = patterns("x[1-10]", "y[1-3]")) .

Comment: I made a mistake.

Comment: ok thanks i am asking because the melt does not give me  the number of combinations that I am expected (15) but only 5...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more base approach. You can generate a combinations of x's and y's using `data.table::CJ` or `expand.grid`. Then go through each combination to perform your linear regression.

```
combi <- CJ(grep("^x", names(d), value=TRUE),grep("^y", names(d), value=TRUE)) 

lmRes <- apply(combi, 1, function(x) {
    fml <- as.formula(paste(x["V2"],"~",x["V1"]))
    lm(fml, d)
})
lmRes
```

Short of generating a large data set from `d` of all combinations of x's and y's before joining with the combinations, there is probably no simpler way to solve this problem by joining tables.

Comment: Thank you . It worked! Nowi need to find a way to retrieve the r.squared and coofficients and p value and map them in a efficient way !

Comment: Hi @Anneclaire you can retrieve them within the apply function as well.